# Switchable custom bootstrap themes with sass

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4, themes

I was able to find many different approaches on how to make a switchable themes in SASS I wasn't able to figure out how can I apply that approach to bootstrap overrides. Let's say I want to have light and dark theme and both themes would override bootstraps colors differently.

```
// Light-theme
$theme-colors: (
    "primary": #8A2F4F
);

// Dark-theme
$theme-colors: (
    "primary": #fff
);
```

In the example above are overrides for `primary` of `theme-colors`. How can I conditionally set them based on theme the user has selected?

Comment: There are many ways, you can have different CSS files, or switch using CSS variables, or add different class to html.

Comment: Well then show me some that I can use to conditionally override bootstrap's variables. F. e. this https://codeburst.io/a-successful-sass-theme-structure-ca9d1c477dc7 is not applicable because I need to conditionally override bootstrap's variables and not use the mixin described in article.

Comment: This is very broad. Are you asking how to switch between different custom CSS themes that were generated via custom SASS, or are you simply asking how to generate different custom CSS themes via SASS?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

there are many ways to do this. I'd suggest you to generate multiple CSS files based on the `_variables.scss` file. All you have to do is build new theme with different variable file. You can check this method in my [public repo](https://github.com/prajwalmr62/prajwalmr62.github.io).

Other way would be to use CSS custom variables (called as custom properties). You can do something like this. I've just copy pasted and altered the CSS. It is just to give an idea.

in sass file,

```
$theme-colors: (
    "primary": var(--primary-color);
);
```

and in other variable file,

```
element.dark {
  --primary-color: black;
} 
element.light {
  --primary-color: white;
}
```

These are two method I would suggest.

Comment: So in the first example you are switching whole css file with javascript? I'm not sure how would I be able to achieve that in react app since the stylesheet is directly imported into the code.

Comment: Yes, I'm that guy who keeps CSS and JS separate.

Comment: It looks like the bootstrap overrides can't be set to CSS variable because if I do that I get error on SASS compilation "Argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color"

Comment: @Prajwal
i got error
```
SassError: $color2: var(--primary-color) is not a color.
    ╷
103 │   @return mix($color-base, $color, $level * $theme-color-interval);
    │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_functions.scss 103:11  theme-color-level()
  node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_tables.scss 101:38     @import
  node_modules\bootstrap\scss\bootstrap.scss 17:9     @import
```

Comment: You should remove your second approach as it does not work.

Comment: @AndréAbreu The second approach is not of using the CSS vars to set the Sass variables. The reason it gives an error is because setting a Sass variable gets compiled during the compilation process and CSS var function var(--primary) gets called during the execution time only. This is the reason it gives compilation error.
However, you can still use CSS vars but only in a css selector styling portion because Sass doesn't compile that in its compilation process. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I did it with React, Bootstrap and SASS:

In an `index.scss` file:

```
div#blue {
  @import './blue.scss';
}

div#red {
  @import './red.scss';
}

// The rest of bootstrap
// Seems to be necessary to import twice to get fonts to work
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Then `red.scss` I over-ride Boostrap where needed:

```
$theme-colors: (
        "primary": red,
);

// The rest of bootstrap
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

`blue.scss` is similar.

Finally my top level React component:

```
import './index.css'
import * as React from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

export const Container = () => {

const [color, setColor] = useState('red');

const buttonClick = () => {
    if (color === 'red') setColor('blue')
    if (color === 'blue') setColor('red')
}

return (
        <div id={theme} >
            Switch themes...
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={buttonClick}>Button</Button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Press the button and it will change from red to blue.   I am guessing that a className rather than a div selector is a better way to do this - but this approach is working for me so I am happy.   Not sure how robust this solution is in complex applications yet.

Comment: This will import Bootstrap three times. I would not suggest this method at all.

Comment: Do you have a better suggestion @mackhax0r?  Are you sure about your assertion?  And if true, the impacts might not be significant in every usage context.

Comment: Absolutely! I tested your method and it did work. For my template, I need to have multiple themes while keeping the size down. I created a themes folder and placed _default.scss, _dark.scss, etc in it, created another file called theme-dark.scss, theme-default.scss. The _dark.scss contains the overrides for coloring, theme-dark.scss imports the theme and bootstrap. This generates multiple files but is lightweight and swappable by changing the css file with js. Your method is fine for 1 or 2 themes, but if it's a heavy-weight website I wouldn't recommend it.